# Calculation of relative performance gain

Tags: mathematical-statistics, repeated-measures, measurement, association-measure

I want to measure the improvement of students using exam marks of semester 1 to semester 3. The following detail should be considered when calculating the measure;

- If Student A get 30 (sem 1) and 50 (sem2), he has obtained 20 marks improvement. If student B obtained 70 (sem1) and 90 (sem2) he has also obtained a 20 marks improvement.However, Student B should get a better performance measure than student A, as reaching 90 from 70 is difficult than reaching 50 from 30.

I want to know, if there is any standard measurement I can use to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If going from $10$ to $30$ is as good as going from $70$ to $90$, and if marks are out of $100$, then you might consider using something related to the the log odds ratio, so in this case the improvement from $m_1/100$ to $m_2/100$ could be measured as

$$\log\left(\dfrac{\tfrac{m_2}{100}}{1-\tfrac{m_2}{100}}\right) -\log\left(\dfrac{\tfrac{m_1}{100}}{1-\tfrac{m_1}{100}}\right)$$

Using natural logarithms, this would give:

- the change from $30/100$ to $50/100$ measured as about $+0.847$
- the change from $70/100$ to $90/100$ measured as about $+1.350$
- the change from $10/100$ to $30/100$ also measured as about $+1.350$

This have the advantage of being

- symmetric measures of change, so $50/100$ to $30/100$ measured as about $-0.847$)
- additive, so the measure of change from $10/100$ to $50/100$ is about $+2.197$ which is equal to the sum of the two measures of changes $1.350+0.847$ going from $10/100$ to $30/100$ and then to $50/100$

If you think the measures are too small, you can multiply them all by a constant

One disadvantage is that moving up from $0/100$ or moving up to $100/100$ is measured as infinite improvement

Comment: Not quite: in my suggestion $10/100$ to $30/100$ is seen as being just as good as $70/100$ to $90/100$.  But if you do not like that because you really only care about approaching $100/100$, then an alternative is $\log\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\tfrac{m_2}{100}}\right) -\log\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\tfrac{m_1}{100}}\right)$

Comment: Hi, is there a way to get rid of the inifinity issue?

Comment: Yes - you can adjust this to avoid $\log(0)$ or $\log(\frac10)$, for example with $\log\left(\dfrac{\tfrac{m_2+1}{102}}{1-\tfrac{m_2+1}{102}}\right) -\log\left(\dfrac{\tfrac{m_1+1}{102}}{1-\tfrac{m_1+1}{102}}\right)$  or with $\log\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\tfrac{m_2}{101}}\right) -\log\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\tfrac{m_1}{101}}\right)$ but this makes it a little more artificial